# How do i make a discord bot that simply gives me a role when i type a certain phrase in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js, roles

I've done **tons** and **tons** of searches but they're all super complex codes such as, when i say "*!Role (role)*" then it gives me the role i specified. However, what i am looking for is something much simpler like if i were to say "*Hello*", then the bot would give me the role that's in the code.

I also tried a lot of the complex ones but most of them used the "`addRole`" function but the output didn't like it

Do you think you can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord JS V12:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    // Checking if the message equals to "hello".
    // Since we use .toLowerCase() which converts any uppercase letter to lowercase, HeLLo will result in hello.
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "hello") {
        // Trying to find the role by ID.
        const Role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("RoleID");
        // Checking if the role exists.
        if (!Role) { // The role doesn't exist.
            message.channel.send(`I'm sorry, the role doesn't exist.`);
        } else { // The role exists.
            // Adding the role to the user.
            message.member.roles.add(Role).catch((error) => {console.error(error)});
            message.channel.send(`You received the role ${Role.name}.`);
        };
    }
});
```

Discord JS V11:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "hello") {
        const Role = message.guild.roles.get("RoleID");
        if (!Role) {
            message.channel.send(`I'm sorry, the role doesn't exist.`);
        } else {
            message.member.addRole(Role).catch((error) => {console.error(error)})
            message.channel.send(`You received the role ${Role.name}.`);
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: It did seem to have a good start but i think there is a problem on my side:

DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\░░\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  method: 'put',
  path: '/guilds/725126311168966749/members/625394153479471136/roles/725139116001329182',
  code: 50013,
  httpStatus: 403
}

Even though i gave my bot full admin access.
what did i do wrong?

Comment: Make sure your bot's role is above the role you want to give. Does that fix your issue?

Comment: Oh my gosh! that makes so much sense now!! thank you SOOO much!